# How to scrape a dropdown list with python

Tags: python, dropdown, scrape

I have to scrape the data from this web page: http://www.mlsa.am/?page_id=368.  This is a dropdown list where the options are: Regions, Areas, Communities, Type of Subsidy, Month and Year. Once these options are selected a table shows up with information on the citizens of these places who get the different kinds of subsidies. The difficulties I am facing at the time to scrape it is that the "Areas" field depends on which "Region" I select, and "Communities" depends on both of them.
This is how the web page looks like when I inspect it, this information 
belongs to the "Regions" (first option) cell:

```
`<!--Մարզեր-->
            <div class="td-pb-row">
                <div class="td-pb-span2"></div>
                <div class="td-pb-span5">
                    Մարզեր <span class="ben-required">*</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select  id="ref_regions_id"  name="ref_regions" style="border:1px solid #0790A2;"  >
                        <option value="0" > Ընտրել </option>
                                                <option  value="1"> ԱՐԱԳԱԾՈՏՆ</option>`

    <option  value="2"> ԱՐԱՐԱՏ</option>

    <option  value="3"> ԱՐՄԱՎԻՐ</option>

    <option  value="4"> ԳԵՂԱՐՔՈՒՆԻՔ</option>

    <option  value="5"> ԼՈՌԻ</option>

    <option  value="6"> ԿՈՏԱՅՔ</option>

    <option  value="7"> ՇԻՐԱԿ</option>

    <option  value="8"> ՍՅՈՒՆԻՔ</option>

    <option  value="9"> ՎԱՅՈՑ ՁՈՐ</option>

    <option  value="10"> ՏԱՎՈՒՇ</option>

    <option  value="11"> ԵՐԵՎԱՆ</option>`

                    </select>
                </div>
```

I am using selenium with python and so far this is my code:

```
`import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\selenium-2.25.0\Driver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
print("loading url into browser...")
def get_all_pages():
    payload={'value':'1'}
driver.get("http://www.mlsa.am/?page_id=368")
print(url.text)
time.sleep(2)`
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't understand the web page

you should create a selenium action chain to select every `option` that you need then click the button.

here is the [reference](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)